# Does a direct subtraction of vector subspaces make sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Consider $E$ a vector space over any field and $U,V$ two subspaces of it, such that $U$ is a subspace of $V$, too.

If I want to refer to the subspace $\bar{U}\space\colon\space U \oplus \bar{U}=V$, my only choice is to say that explicitly, there is no operation between subspaces that yields $\bar{U}$ nor a shorter way to express it symbolically. To me, it is shocking that there exists no notation for this, because I have encountered more than one a situation where it would've come in handy. I would've used it more than, say, Knuth's up-arrow notation.

I thought of defining a "direct subtraction" of sorts, so
$$U \ominus V \space\colon=\bar{U}, \space\space\space\space\space \text{where} \space U\oplus \bar{U}=V.$$

My questions are: does this make sense?, is this notation not well-defined?, is there any situation where it can lead to confusion?

I have tried, but failed to find any problems with it, so far. In fact, if I'm not wrong, the subspace $U\ominus V$ would be naturally isomorphic to $U/V$. But, then again, the fact that I'm not able to find any notation similar to this one makes me believe that I'm going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I've never seen this notation before.

Comment: I think without further structure it is best, as you say, to have the "subtraction" produce the quotient $U/V$, rather than attempting to produce a subspace of $U$. Indeed, in somewhat fancier situations, e.g., in Banach spaces, often there _is_ no complementary subspace at all, much less any sort of canonical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *the* subspace $\bar{U}$, you are making an error. Unless there is extra structure on $V$, there is no canonical choice of such a subspace.

Consider $\Bbb{R}^2 = \text{$x$-axis}\oplus \text{$y$-axis}$, but also $\Bbb{R}^2 = \text{$x$-axis}\oplus \text{the line $x=y$}$.

On the other hand, if there is extra structure, this sometimes exists, but we usually call it something different. For example if $V$ is an inner product space, we call your "direct subtraction" the orthogonal complement, $U^\perp$.